# Auto format date parameter for a Ormlite queryRaw

Tags: java, date-format, ormlite

When using `dao.queryRaw(String, RowMapper, String... params)` is there a way to auto format a date when passing as parameter, based on the specified format on field declaration?

**Example:**

Data class declaration:

```
public class Example {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING, format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
    Date date;
}
```

Query:

```
String query = "select * from example where date = ?"
String[] params = { new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()) };
return dao.queryRaw(query, dao.getRawRowMapper(), params);
```

Is there a way to ask Ormlite the date format or to make it format the date to me, instead of repeating (or using the same constant) string?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of hacky solution:

```
String query = "select * from example where date = ?"

// cast dao from interface to implemenation :-(
// and get the field info from its table info
FieldType fieldType = ((BaseDaoImpl<Example, Integer>) dao).getTableInfo().getFieldTypeByColumnName("date");
// format parameter
String param = DateStringType.getSingleton().javaToSqlArg(fieldType, new Date()).toString();
String[] params = {param};
return dao.queryRaw(query, dao.getRawRowMapper(), params);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure using the `Date` directly works with the `QueryBuilder`.  It's a problem however if you need to to use the raw query which only deals in strings.

```java
List<Example> results = 
     exampleDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("date", new Date()).query();
```

If you can't use `QueryBuilder` then one hack is to encode the `format = "..."` string as a static and add a `dateToString(Date)` to `Example`.  Something like this should work:

```java
public class Example {
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING, format = DATE_FORMAT)
    Date date;
    ...
    public String dateToString(Date date) {
        // remember that SimpleDateFormat is not reentrant
        return new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).format(new Date());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used a simple example just to illustrate the problem, but since I need custom filtering and joining other tables, using `queryBuilder` is not an option.